# ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2 login without external login providers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

How do you configure asp.net core mvc 2.2 by just using the default local login without external login providers?

I can't seem to find a way to remove this:

```
Use another service to log in.

There are no external authentication services configured. See this article for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.
```

I only want to use local accounts for now (and maybe later add external providers).

```
      services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4);
```

Comment: You'll need to [scaffold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) the `Account/Login` page and modify its .cshtml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not configurable. If you look at the implementation of the [Login page](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/f7cb01864b6a87dc01a0af3bf4047a59b6ff2964/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V4/Account/Login.cshtml#L49-L76), you will see that it doesn't use any options, but just renders the messages.

> Use another service to log in.

is rendered always and

> There are no external authentication services configured. See this article for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.

is rendered if there are no external login providers.

There is no way to remove the messages using identity builder or something like that. The only way would be to [scaffold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) the Login page (as [Kirk Larkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630078/kirk-larkin) pointed out) and remove the messages from the `Login.cshtml` file.

Comment: ok perfect. scaffolding seems indeed to be the solution. (+Is there a way to configure your own email+smtp server for sending a password reset/confirmation email using the default login?)

Comment: @juFo Yes, there is. You need to provide your implementation of `IEmailSender` and register it: `services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();`. You can find more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, but I would like to point out that this is a pretty bad solution from Microsoft. There is no one who would want this in production, which basically makes this useless without scaffolding for even the simplest app.